# Property missing type in React/Typescript while trying to pass a bool and interface to component state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am new to React and Typescript and I can't find the correct way I should be passing these into the React.Componet state. My code still works as expected but I would like to know what I am doing wrong!

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, { isLoading: boolean, thisCoffeeShop: ICoffeeShop }> {
constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true                    
    }       
}
//....
}
```

}

I assume its Typescript throwing me

```
"Property 'thisCoffeeShop' is missing in type '{ isLoading: true; }' but required in type 'Readonly<{ isLoading: boolean; thisCoffeeShop: ICoffeeShop; }>'."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is missing `thisCoffeeShop` that you said would be in it.

```
this.state = {
  isLoading: true   
  thisCoffeeShop: {...} // no idea what structure ICoffeeShop is              
}
```

If you don't want this to be required to start, you can make the property optional.

`React.Component<{}, { isLoading: boolean, thisCoffeeShop?: ICoffeeShop }>`

Comment: I did have it like this, but then it complains thisCoffeeShop is missing properties. Can I set it as empty? Since I fill it with a api call in componentDidMount()

Comment: You can do that or add a `?` to the end of your type declaration to mark it optional.

Comment: Ah adding the ? in the type declarations worked! Thanks a bunch.